# Custom function Wordpress not stopping after return

Tags: php, wordpress, function, return

Good day!

As the title says my custom function is not stopping after i do return.
I have created a child theme and create a function inside the functions.php file.

What i try to achieve is show the category title otherwise the string home as title.

What i end up getting now is both the category title and the string of home if i click on a category.

HTML:

```
<h3><?php echo header_title() ?> </h3>
```

PHP:

```
function header_title() {


    if(single_cat_title() != NULL) {
        return single_cat_title();
    } else {
        return 'home';
    }
}
```

Anyone knows what went wrong here?

Any help will be appreciated here :)

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough info to help debug this.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not stopping'?

Comment: I have edited my question, i hope its more clear now what the problem is. sorry for not clearing up things enough!

Comment: Its that exact function and the header_title isn't called anywhere else. I taught it might has something to do with wordpress since im new to it. but i dont think anything is wrong here with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`single_cat_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title) will only return a value if you set the second (`$display`) argument to `false`.  Since you're not specifying it, it's `echo`ing the value, returning nothing, and you're dropping through to your `else` condition.

Try providing that parameter (eg `if(single_cat_title('', false) != NULL) {`) in both your calls.  Or store the result.

Comment: Thanks! and good reference to the codex! makes it a lot more clear! i was echo'ing twice ;-)

Comment: No problem - glad to help